# Select rows with alphabet characters only

Tags: python, regex, alphabet, datumbox

My data are in the following format:

```
data = [['@datumbox', '#machinelearning'],
 ['@datumbox', '#textanalysis'],
 ['@things_internet', '#iot'],
 ['@things_internet', '#h...'],
 ['@custmrcom', '#analytics123'],
 ['@custmrcom', '#strategy...123'],
 ['@custmrcom', '#1knowledgetweet'],
 ['@tamaradull', '#@bigbrother']]
```

I would like to check whether the hashtag contains any non-alphabet. If so, the respective rows are removed.

The desired output is:

```
data = [['@datumbox', '#machinelearning'],
 ['@datumbox', '#textanalysis'],
 ['@things_internet', '#iot']]
```

I think I need to use re.sub (e.g, re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')). This is what I have so far:

```
newdata = []

for item in data:
    regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')
    if regex.match(item[1]):
        newdata.append([item[0], item[1]])
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: Remember to exclude `#` too, because it's a non-alphabet character.

Comment: # is hashtag so I want to keep it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a list comprehension with a condition:

```
newdata = [x for x in data if x[1][1:].isalpha()]
print newdata
```

Gives the output

```
[['@datumbox', '#machinelearning'], ['@datumbox', '#textanalysis'], ['@things_internet', '#iot']]
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer:

```
for item in data:
    if re.match("^#[A-Za-z]+$", item[1]):
        newdata.append(item)
```